# How to export actors (point clouds, lines, splines) from VTK viewer?

Tags: c++, vtk, point-cloud-library

I am working with PCL and vtk viewer and I have created a scene which consists of a pointcloud, some lines and some splines. How can I export these actors in one file that would be readable by Blender or Cinema4D? I have already tried vtkOBJExporter:

```
vtkOBJExporter* vtkExporter = vtkOBJExporter::New();
vtkExporter->SetRenderWindow(this->viewer->getRenderWindow());
vtkExporter->SetFilePrefix("/tmp/scene");
vtkExporter->Write();
```

This does not seem to save my actors. When I try to open the file with Blender or with view3dscene it seems empty.